# Git log: "unknown date format"

Tags: git, docker, git-log, strftime

This is the command I'm running, and its error:

```
# git log --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=format-local:"%y-%m-%d %k:%M"
fatal: unknown date format format-local:%y-%m-%d %k:%M
```

The same command works fine on other machines.  I'm running into this error inside an ubuntu docker container.  Other formats throw the same error:

```
# git log --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=format-local:"%M"
fatal: unknown date format format-local:%M
# git log --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=format-local:"%m"
fatal: unknown date format format-local:%m
# git log --pretty=format:"%ad" --date=format:"%m"
fatal: unknown date format format:%m
```

It seems like I'm missing a date-formatting dependency that wasn't a part of the docker image.

EDIT: I'm using git version 1.9.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `git --version` to view the version of Git you are running.

`--date=format:strfime-format` is new in Git version 2.6.0.  If you are running in an environment that has an older version of Git, it's simply not available.

The `--date=format-local:` feature is new in Git version 2.7.0 (so between those two you can use `format:` but not `format-local:`, even though you can use `--date=local`).

Comment: This was it.  Fixed it with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade git`.

Comment: Actually, the docker image wouldn't upgrade past v1.9.1, but I fixed it with [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/500733/533341).  I'm now using version 2.16.5, but `format-local` is working now.

Comment: Git 1.9 is pretty ancient now. The only thing worse that I know of is CentOS, which is stuck on 1.7. It's sometimes useful to be able to deal with really old software versions, though, which is where version control comes in. :-) I actually found the above version numbers by looking at the Git repository for Git.

Comment: I also found out that git versions older than 2.7.4 have serious vulnerabilities ([`CVE-2016-2324`](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2016-2324) & [`CVE-2016-2315`](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2016-2315)).  Definitely worth upgrading in this case.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14 upgrading Git we need this way: https://askubuntu.com/a/579591/768956